# Media Query not working with adjustment to browser size adjustment

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been using Media Queries for making my website mobile responsive. I have been using Google Chromes emulator feature to test this and it all works great.

Something I do not understand however is the fact that when I adjust the browser, it does not react properly with the media query.
I am guessing because I am only changing the width of the screen but not the height and that is I suppose causing an issue I do not know how to properly deal with.

Here is the media query code I have implemented into my CSS file(Incase you would need to see it).

```
    /* MEDIA QUERIES FOR VERTICAL VIEWING */

/*For Older, Smaller Smart Phones */
@media screen and (min-width:300px)
{
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 70vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:5vh;
        width:33vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

}




/*For Modern Smart Phones */
@media screen and (min-width:350px)
{
    .paral
    {
        min-height: 60vh;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height:100vh;
    }
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 7vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 40px;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 70vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:30vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

}
/* For Small Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width:500px)
{
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8.5vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 80vw;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:30vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }

}

/* For Medium Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width:700px)
{
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8.5vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 6vh;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:35vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 80vw;
    }

}

/* For Large Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width:1000px)
{
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 7vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 6vh;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:35.8vh;
        font-size: 5vw;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 80vw;
    }

}

/* For Standard Laptops */
@media screen and (min-width:1280px)
{
    .paral h1
    {
        color: white;
        font-size: 4vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 4vh;
        word-wrap:normal;
    }
    .paral p
    {
        font-size: 4vh;
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 6vh;
    }
    .btn-home-margin
    {
        margin-top:6vh;
        width:36vh;
        font-size: 2vw;
    }
    .paral-home-setting
    {
        width: 50vw;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share screenshot of rendering after browser resizing

Comment: I think you should be using max-width instead of min-width because as u know max will restrict those styles only for that size min-width will be applied for all so it might be a problem i guess

Comment: @Master.Deep I have got it working, I am using the max width version, thanks too!

Comment: @Manjunath I have been using that max width and it is working now, thanks!